# how to inject agurment const& type c++

Tags: c++

I have a constructor of class Clock.

```
 Clock(CLOCK_TYPE type_, ClockTime const& initialTime, double const  driftPerSecond, char const * const name)
```

In main function, i create new instance of class. But I don't know how to pass arguement to second arguement(ClockTime const& initialTime ). 
this is contructor of ClockTime.

```
ClockTime::ClockTime()
: hour_(0),
minute_(0),
second_(0),
secondsPerTick_(0),
deltaTime_(0)
{
    recordStartTime();
}

ClockTime::ClockTime(int hour, int minute, int second, int secondsPerTick)
: hour_(hour),
minute_(minute),
second_(second),
secondsPerTick_(secondsPerTick),
deltaTime_(0)
{
    recordStartTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example the following way

```
Clock clock( /*...*/, ClockTime( h, m, s, t ), /*...*/ );
```

or the following way

```
Clock clock( /*...*/, { h, m, s, t }, /*...*/ );
```

where h, m, s, t some arguments for the constructor ClockTime.

Or you can use the default constructor of class ClockTime

```
Clock clock( /*...*/, ClockTime(), /*...*/ );
```

Comment: Note that all your examples provide ClockTime as rvalue, but lvalue is an other possibility.

Comment: @Jarod42 If he had an lvalue he would not ask his question because there is no problem to use this argument in the constructor call.

Answer (score 0):

This `const&` just means that function will not modify your `Clocktime` object. It doesn't actually affect the ways you pass the argument. So the following will work:

```
ClockTime t;
Clock c(..., t, ...);
```